# @angular/common/http HttpClient of post method awalys return error?

Tags: angular

i use @angular/common/http
HttpClient Module of post method

```
const httpOptions: object = {
           headers: new HttpHeaders({
                Authorization: this.token,
               'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
              }),
    };
    HttpClient.post(url, JSON.stringify(json), httpOptions)
        .subscribe(res => {  
          console.log('success', res);
        },(error: any) => {
         // It always comes back here, even if it's successful
          console.log('fail', error);
        });
      }
```

Comment: why'd you have content-type, in three different places ??

Comment: sorry, The third place doesn't

Comment: can you show returned error ?

Comment: Please add the entire .ts file

Comment: thank you everybody.. because receive data type and server send data type differ.